# Sequential constraints on table columns

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Say I have a table with a `created`, `uploaded`, `processed` and `archived` columns, all of which accept a date. However, I want it so the fields have to be updated in chronological order and you can't skip a step, but the trailing steps don't have to be set until they're ready (i.e., created <= uploaded <= processed <= archived). I implemented this like so:

```
create table batch (
  id        number primary key,
  created   date   default sysdate not null,
  uploaded  date,
  processed date,
  archived  date,

  check (uploaded  is null or uploaded  >= created),
  check (processed is null or processed >= uploaded),
  check (archived  is null or archived  >= processed)
);
```

This works, but it allows you to skip steps. For example, I can insert an arbitrary value for `processed` if `uploaded` is still `null`. I presume this to be because the `null` comparison is always vacuous. Do I therefore have to do something like:

```
create table batch (
  id        number primary key,
  created   date   default sysdate not null,
  uploaded  date,
  processed date,
  archived  date,

  check (uploaded  is null or uploaded >= created),
  check (processed is null or (uploaded is not null and processed >= uploaded)),
  check (archived  is null or (processed is not null and archived >= processed))
);
```

Is there a neater way?

Comment: I think your suggestion is fine although I would go for a different design. I would have a different table to handle the steps this way in the future if this workflow change it will be much more easy to adapt. And the workflow you would check with a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went for my own solution:

```
create table batch (
  id        number primary key,
  created   date   default sysdate not null,
  uploaded  date,
  processed date,
  archived  date,

  check (uploaded  is null or uploaded >= created),
  check (processed is null or (uploaded is not null and processed >= uploaded)),
  check (archived  is null or (processed is not null and archived >= processed))
);
```

Granted that this constrains the workflow to this static schema, as mentioned by Jorge, but that's a tradeoff I'm willing to accept!

Answer (score 2):

I think your design is sound. I would split the checks for chronological order and the NULL checks, but this is only a question of style, not logic.

```
create table batch (
  id        number primary key,
  created   date   default sysdate not null,
  uploaded  date,
  processed date,
  archived  date,

  CHECK (created <= uploaded),
  CHECK (uploaded <= processed),
  CHECK (processed <= archived),

  CHECK (uploaded IS NOT NULL OR processed IS NULL),
  CHECK (processed IS NOT NULL OR archived IS NULL)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create 4 tables. One for each process.

1. batches_created
2. batches_uploaded
3. batches_processed
4. batches_archived

> ```
> create table batches_created (  
>   id        number primary key,  
>   created   date   default sysdate not null  
> );
>
> create table batches_uploaded (  
>   id        number primary key,  
>   created   date   default sysdate not null,  
>   constraint fk_batch_uploaded FOREIGN KEY( id ) REFERENCES batches_created( id )  
> );
>
> create table batches_processed (
>   id        number primary key,  
>   created   date   default sysdate not null,  
>   constraint fk_batch_processed FOREIGN KEY( id ) REFERENCES batches_uploaded( id )  
> );
>
> create table batches_archived (  
>   id        number primary key,  
>   created   date   default sysdate not null,  
>   constraint fk_batch_archived FOREIGN KEY( id ) REFERENCES batches_processed( id )  
> );
> ```

So you can't have a batch archived without first create it, uploade it, and then process it.

Comment: Thank you for this...although I wouldn't necessarily call it "neater" ;)

Comment: @Xophmeister: you have to add constraints to ensure there are not more than one batches_uploaded per batches_created etc...

Comment: I like downvote without comment. No chance to improve.